# HTTPS/SSL Issues on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have this Multidocker configuration, my HTTP traffic works fine no any problems, however, I get 408 every time I try to use https

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "users-managment",
            "image": "....",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 256,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 3000,
                    "containerPort": 3000
                }
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "PORT",
                    "value": "3000" 
                }
            ],
            "mountPoints": []
        },
        {
            "name": "presence",
            "image": "...ecr",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 256,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 3001,
                    "containerPort": 3001
                }
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "USERS_SERVICE",
                    "value": "http://users-managment:3000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "PORT",
                    "value": "3001" 
                }
            ],
            "links": ["users-managment"],
            "mountPoints": []
        },
        {
            "name": "signaling",
            "image": "...dkr.ecr...",
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "PORT",
                    "value": "3002" 
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 256,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 3002,
                    "containerPort": 3002
                }
            ],
            "links": ["users-managment"],
            "mountPoints": []
        },
        {
            "name": "api-gateway",
            "image": "...dkr.ecr...",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 128,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "containerPort": 80
                },
                {
                    "hostPort": 443,
                    "containerPort": 443
                }
            ],
            "links": ["signaling", "presence", "users-managment"],
            "mountPoints": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I have 3 node.js servers and a Nginx server all the images are uploaded to Amazon Elastic container repository,  I added an SSL certificate with amazon certificate Manager and already open a port 443 in my classic load balancer in elastic beanstalk load balancer configuration, I checked the security group that is attached to the EB application and it redirects all HTTP and HTTPS traffic to the load balancer as well.

this is the nginx configuration

```
#The actual HTTPS server
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location /users {
        proxy_pass http://users-managment:3000;
    }

    location /docs/users {
       proxy_pass http://users-managment:3000; 
    }

    location /ice/servers {
        proxy_pass http://signaling:3002;
    }

    #For Server-1
    location /signaling/ {
        #Configure proxy to pass data to upstream node1
        proxy_pass http://signaling:3002/socket.io/;
        #HTTP version 1.1 is needed for sockets
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    #For Server-2
    location /presence/ {
        #Configure proxy to pass data to upstream node2
        proxy_pass http://presence:3001/socket.io/;
        #HTTP version 1.1 is needed for sockets
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by Setting the instance port to 80 and the instance protocol to HTTP while keeping the load balancer port 443 and protocol HTTPS

Comment: You have no idea how long I tried to solve this, thank you!

Comment: It took a while for me to stumble upon this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

This is the official doc from AWS. It explains the same thing.