# How can I set redirect from http to https on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk I and I have https.

I would like to set (for all ports) to redirect from http to https.

How can I do it ? It is possible set it in aws dashboard? In Modify load balancer section?

I was trying to use:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/http-redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

in `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` but it is not working.

Comment: Which ElasticBeanstalk type are you using?  Some use Apache and some use Nginx.

Comment: @stdunbar Where can I find this information? There is nothing about it in settings.

Comment: Just: Platform: `Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux` , tierName: `WebServer`

Comment: That environment runs Nginx.  Looks like there is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494561/https-ssl-issues-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-multicontainer-docker-configuration)

Comment: Usually you do the redirection on your ALB.

Comment: ALB does support redirection, although Elastic Beanstalk doesn't support configuration of it. It is possible to configure using an ebextension override to do it, but it is a bit messy. See https://github.com/stefansundin/rssbox/blob/1e40fe60f888ad0143e5c4fb83c1471986032963/.ebextensions/resources.config#L38-L92.